# Running Windows XP with VMWare Fusion from a Fujitsu-Siemens recovery disk

Tags: windows, mac, vmware-fusion

I have installed a trial version from VMWare Fusion. I had (sold now) a very old Fujitu-Siemens laptop (from around 2001) which came with two recovery disks. One recovery disk is a Windows XP installer, the other is a disk with drivers.

If I install Windows XP from the recovery disk, will it run in VMWare Fusion?

---

Yes, I need XP, not 7.

Answer (score 2):

It probably won't activate windows properly as the VMWare BIOS emulation wont be emulating the Fujitsu SLP.

More information here on SLP: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457054.aspx

Also it may be worth pointing out that the windows CD you got with the Fujitsu should have gone with it and is now unlicenced anyways.

You are probably gonna need to buy a new copy.